# カスタムキーボードの Voice Over

Tags: ios, xcode, objective-c, swift5

全盲の嫁の為に、お手本を見ながらカスタムキーボードを作成中です。
実機テストで分かったことですが、 Voice Overによるボタンの読み上げをしてくれません。
コードの追加が必要なのでしょうか？

```
#import "KeyboardViewController.h"
#import "Keyboard.h"
@interface KeyboardViewController ()
@property (strong,nonatomic) Keyboard *keyboard;
@end

@implementation KeyboardViewController

- (void)updateViewConstraints {
    [super updateViewConstraints];

    // Add custom view sizing constraints here
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Perform custom UI setup here
    self.keyboard = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Keyboard" owner:nil options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];
    [self addGesturesToKeyboard];
    self.inputView = self.keyboard;

}


- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
}

- (void)textWillChange:(id<UITextInput>)textInput {
    // The app is about to change the document's contents. Perform any preparation here.
}

- (void)textDidChange:(id<UITextInput>)textInput {
    // The app has just changed the document's contents, the document context has been updated.

    UIColor *textColor = nil;
    if (self.textDocumentProxy.keyboardAppearance == UIKeyboardAppearanceDark) {
        textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    } else {
        textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
}

#pragma mark Keyboards
- (void)addGesturesToKeyboard{
    [self.keyboard.deleteKey addTarget:self action:@selector(pressDeleteKey) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.keyboard.spaceKey addTarget:self action:@selector(pressSpaceKey) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [self.keyboard.returnKey addTarget:self action:@selector(pressReturnKey) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   //Change to next keyboard
    [self.keyboard.globeKey addTarget:self action:@selector(advanceToNextInputMode) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

for (UIButton *Key in self.keyboard.keysArray) {
    [Key addTarget:self action:@selector(pressKey:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];}
     }
- (void)pressDeleteKey{
        [self.textDocumentProxy deleteBackward];
    }
-(void)pressSpaceKey{
    [self.textDocumentProxy insertText:@" "];
}
-(void)pressReturnKey{
        [self.textDocumentProxy insertText:@"\n"];}
     -(void)pressKey:(UIButton *)key{
    [self.textDocumentProxy insertText:[key currentTitle]];

     }

@end
```

Comment: コードを別に書く必要があったのですね。ありがとうございます。これで実機テストしてみます。

Comment: 実機テストしてみましたが、やはり読み上げはしませんでした。原因が分かりません…

Comment: 作成されたカスタムキーボードのキーのボタンを押すときにそのキーのタイトルなどをVoiceOverで読み上げたい、ということですよね？
コードを見る限りキーのボタンはUIButtonのようですので何もしなくてもボタンのtitleプロパティの値が読み上げられるはずです。
もしボタンが画像を表示しているだけでtitleを設定してない、のであればVoiceOver用のラベルを`[button setAccessibilityLabel:@"あ"];`のように設定する必要がありますが、コードを書いたというのはこのことでしょうか？
もしこの辺りのことを一通りやってもできないということであれば詳しい情報が必要なので、全体のコードやスクリーンショットなどを使ってもう少し詳しく問題ややりたいことを教えてください。

Comment: title設定もしてたのですが、偶然なのかiosのアップデートを終わってからは、読み上げるようになりました。

Comment: 偶然で動いていた Voice Overが、また作動しなくなりました。